# Can I use a voltage divider instead of an external battery with an SCR?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, scr

I have this circuit

- 12VDC battery
- boost converter up to 390V DC-DC
- capacitor 1000 uf 450V
- diode 10A10
- thyristor BTW69-1200 (I gt 8-80 mA / V gt 1.5v max)

I managed to make this circuit work with an external battery:

[image]

Now I want to make the circuit work without this external circuit battery

I will use a voltage divider to get 1.5V from the 12V source but I do not know exactly how the circuit should be

Here my prototype circuit.  The voltage going to thyristor now should be 1.5V.  I also add this 33ohm resistor to make the current to thyristor 40mA

[image]

[image]

Is this circuit right?